# Python List Slicing inserting space

Tags: python, list, slice

I am working on a program to manipulate an array. It is working but I see some extra white spaces inserted in values.

Is there a way on how to avoid the space being inserted in the output ?

```
Input: arr = [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0] 
Output = [1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4]
Expected Output = [1,0,0,2,3,0,0,4]
```

```
class Solution(object):
 def duplicateZeros(self,arr):
  i=0
  while(i < len(arr)):
   if arr[i] == 0:
    arr = arr[:i] + [0] + arr[i:arrlen-1]
    i+=2
   else:
    i+=1
  print(arr)
```

Comment: This is just how python displays lists when you print them. There are no spaces in the data.

Comment: The spaces are not being added, lists just print in the format `[i, j]` not `[i,j]`.

Comment: The space is irrelevant to the data; it’s simply a display feature to increase readability.

Comment: write own method to format data from list - ie. `print( ",".join( str(x) for x in arr ))`

Comment: Your [mre] should just be `print([1,2,3])`. The code you have posted is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: problem is not your list (which has only numbers without spaces) but how `print()` format list (it add space after every `,` to make it more readable for human). If you want to display without spaces then you have to convert list to string on your own before you print it - ie. `text =  '[' + ",".join( str(x) for x in arr ) + ']'` and later `print(text)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace`:

```
print(str(arr).replace(' ', ''))
```